# Non-Reactive copy of Pinia store remains reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pinia

I have a Pinia store with an action that saves the state of another store. This allows a user to create custom "default" settings and return to them, instead of using `$reset()` to return to the system-set starting state.

This is working for some states, with the exception of a state that is an array. The store copy is remaining reactive, when the other states are not.

Example of the code below:

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

//My Settings store
export const useSettingsStore = defineStore('settingsStore,' {
    state: () => ({
        settingA: 10,
        settingB: 'Name Only',
        settingC: [1,2,3]
    })
})

export const useCopyStore = defineStore('copyStore,' {
    state: () => ({
        settingsCopy: []
    }),
    actions: {
        takeCopy() { //save a copy of current settings, as non-reactive
            this.settingsCopy = [];
            this.settingsCopy.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(useSettingsStore().$state)))
        }
    }
})
```

The settings within the `settingsStore` are `v-model`-ed to a frontend UI.
When I use Vue devtools to inspect the copy, `settingA` and `settingB` are non-reactive as desired. When I change the values using the frontend, I can see the values within the `settingC` `settingsCopy` and original store changing. How can I prevent this?

Comment: The term "non-reactive" is supposedly incorrectly used here. Pinia state is reactive by nature. If your problem is that settingsCopy is magically linked to useSettingsStore  state then it's specific to how you use them. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem.

Comment: My goal is to take a non-reactive copy of the `useSettingsStore` that is static and will not change when a state within the Settings Store is modified. Is my approach above valid, in theory?

Comment: Yes. I don't see problems with it, unless you use settingsCopy incorrectly later